# Facebook still getting access token while logged out ( JS and PHP )

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am currently building a website and my Wordpress theme already supports login to Facebook via the JS SDK. Below is my `FB.init`

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
                FB.init({
                    appId       : 'xxxxxxxx'
                    , status    : true
                    , cookie    : true
                    , xfbml     : true
                    , oauth     : true
                    , version    : 'v2.2'
                });
            };
```

Since i want to do some background checks before outputting stuff on HTML i'm also using the PHP SDK. ( I do not use the PHP for login purposes due to having more redirects while the JS one is straight forward (pop up and you're done).

To make the requests i am using the `FacebookJavascriptLoginHelper` with the below code to get the session i need for the request.

```
$helper = new FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper();
    try {
        $session = $helper->getSession();
    } catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
        // When Facebook returns an error
    } catch(\Exception $ex) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
    }
```

All good so far. Each time i refresh the page i'm getting a new `access token` from the JS SDK and use it in the case i need to make a request.
Problem is on the logout part of all this.

If i use the `FB.logout` the user is logged out of the facebook, even in his browser and has to login again which is absolutely not acceptable. 
I can by pass this "issue" by simply checking if there is a logged in user before going on and start asking for new Facebook sessions but is that the way i should go ?

When i loggout of the wordpress i can still receive access tokens and make requests to the server for some time. Close to 10-15 minutes i think. After that i do not receive anything and have to log in again.

EDIT: Also i noticed that even if i don't log out, if i don't refresh for a short period of time i get no `session` `(access token)`. If i refresh once and then the second time i do get one

Comment: you need to carefully re-phrase this question and show code you are using.

Comment: If you do _not_ log out of Facebook completely, then the JS SDK will recognize that and automatically log the user in to your app again on next visit – that is how it’s supposed to work. If you were to use the PHP SDK only, then you could delete the cookies that it sets under your domain, and the user won’t be recognized any more until you redirect to the login dialog the next time.